# ListView VB6 and SQL-SERVER, can someone look at my code?

Tags: sql-server, listview, vb6

I posted a question asking to help with populating ListView in vb6 with data from SQL-SERVER. So I was able to do that. I'm loading the names of sports, and have ID assigned to each value. Here's the code:

```
lvwExpenditures.ListItems.Clear
With lvwExpenditures
    .FullRowSelect = True
    .View = lvwReport
    .LabelEdit = lvwManual
    .ColumnHeaders.Add , "FldName", "Expense", 2200
    .ColumnHeaders.Add , "ID", "ID", 0
End With


g_strSQL = "Select FldName, ID, Label, SortOrder from dbo.tblText_References   where fldname ='expenditureitems'"
rs.Open g_strSQL, g_cnDatabase, adOpenStatic
Debug.Print g_strSQL
With rs
  Do While Not .EOF
        Set lvwItem = lvwExpenditures.ListItems.Add(, ,  .Fields("Label").Value)
        lvwItem.SubItems(1) = .Fields("ID").Value 'Populate Date column
     .MoveNext
  Loop
End With
Set rs = Nothing
```

So now, I need to let the user select multiple items from the ListView if they so desire. I did it with checkboxes, but I'm trying to do this without them. Also, if a user selects multiple items, what would my Insert statement look like. I would only need to save the ID's associated with the ids, and concatonate them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
dim g_strSQL as string
g_strSQL = "SELECT ID, Desc FROM refTest_Insurance Where statuscode = 'a'  ORDER BY InsuranceID ASC"
Debug.Print g_strSQL

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim g_RS As ADODB.Recordset

    ' db_file contains the Access database's file name.
    ' Open a connection.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Your connection string here"
    conn.Open

    ' Get the records.
    Set g_RS = conn.Execute(g_strSQL, , adCmdText)

    'Set URLs = New Collection
    Do While Not g_RS.EOF
        List1.AddItem g_RS!Desc 
        'URLs.Add CStr(g_RS!Id)

        g_RS.MoveNext
    Loop

    ' Close the recordset and connection.
    g_RS.Close
    conn.Close
```

Comment: Which part does not work?  Do you get a populated recordset?

Comment: Yes, I run the query in the SQL-SERVER and see that correct values are being selected. The Code gets stuck on SUBITEMS. This is for my code, sorry did not notice your name. I thought you were referring to my code.